# Boost.Asio simple client server model do not return a response

Tags: networking, boost-asio

Trying for first time to build my client server on boost.asio, the server response to client is empty.
i am not sure what is the problem - will be happy to any help.

Server code:

```
const std::string message = "Hi";
        boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
        try
        {
                boost::asio::io_service io_service;
                tcp::endpoint endpoint = tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 12345);
                tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service,endpoint);
                for (;;){
                        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
                        acceptor.accept(socket);
                   boost::asio::write(socket,boost::asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);
                }

        }
        catch (std::exception& e){
                std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
```

Client code:

```
        try{
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query(IP, "12345");
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
        for (;;)
        {
                std::string buf;
                boost::system::error_code error;



                size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);           
                if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
                        break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
                else if (error)
                        throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
                std::cout.write(buf.data());
        }
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.read_some` reads data into a buffer which is defined by `boost::asio::buffer(buf)`. 
The size of this buffer is determined by `buf.size()`. 
In your case `std::string` is empty, 
so the buffer for reading bytes is empty. 
`read_some` *reads 0 bytes* and returns.

Because the server always send a message consisted of 2 bytes, you can resize `buf` to hold 2 bytes:

```
std::string buf;
buf.resize(2);
boost::system::error_code error;
size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error); 
// now read_some reads at most 2 bytes into buf
```

Because at the server side a socket is created, it sends message and it is destroyed,
you can use `dynamic_buffer` + `transfer_all` + `boost::asio::read` to read non-fixed length message:

```
std::string buf;
size_t len = boost::asio::read (socket,boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(buf),
    boost::asio::transfer_all(),error);
if (len && error == boost::asio::error::eof)
{ 
  // data was read from server and eof is reached
  // do sth with buf
}
```

`boost::asio::read` reads data until buffer is read fully or some errors occur (for example `eof` - socket at server side was closed).
The server sends data, client reads data, socket at server is destroyed and client gets `eof` from `asio::read`.